# Why does my GridView switch out of Edit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

***Before anyone answers this***, I found the bug in my code, and posted my answer below. I'm leaving this question up (unless someone really cares) as a cautionary tale to always bind your bleeping `GridView`.

---

**Preface/Background**

I'm (ab)using the ASP.NET WebForms controls in an odd way. I know.

I'm working on an application where students are expected to list some school activities they've participated in. Students can add several rows, and -- just for general workflow reasons -- I decided to separate the `GridView` that displays their "saved" entries from the "details" area where they add/update their activities.

The Edit/Update pieces work beautifully. I can add new items, use baked-in validation that I tied into my classes (which is what all the extra `span` tags that have `class="error"` attributes display). I really wanted to make this idiot-proof, so the button they click to add a new activity will also validate and add their information to the `GridView` (provided the item passes validation), clear the Details controls, and behave as normal.

**Problem Description**

I started some basic testing on this, and found that if I edit an activity, break one (or more) of the validation rules in that class, and click the "Add New Activity" button, my `GridView` reverts that row from the `EditItemTemplate` back to the normal `ItemTemplate`.

As far as I can tell, my `EditIndex` never strays from the row I'm still editing. In fact, if I trigger another postback, the `GridView` shows the correct `EditIndex`!

I've tried re-setting the `EditIndex` and switched my `e.Cancel = true` to a `return` statement. Nothing's worked. Considering that the `EditIndex's` value stays constant through multiple postbacks, I have to think there's something weird going on here.

I've posted the markup and C# code below. Both are pretty absurdly long -- I refactor the hell out of my functions -- so I apologize in advance, and thank anyone brave enough (or bored enough) to offer advice.

Also, I can provide screenshots if anyone would rather see this happening instead of (or in addition to) reading through my markup/code.

**`GridView`**

```
<asp:GridView ID="schoolActivities" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="edit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "Details") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>Editing...</EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Months per Year
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "MonthsPerYear") %></ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Date</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "ActivityDate") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Total Hours Outside Class Time
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "TotalHours") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**"Details" section**

```
<br />
<button type="button" id="newActivity" runat="server">Add New Activity</button>
<br />

<fieldset id="schoolActivityFields" runat="server" visible="false">
    <legend>Activity</legend>

    <span>Details:</span>
    <span>
        <textarea id="schoolActivityDetails" class="schoolActivityDetails" runat="server"></textarea>
        <br />
        <span id="schoolActivityDetailsError" class="error" runat="server"></span>
    </span>
    <br />

    <span>Months per Year:</span>
    <span>
        <select id="schoolActivityMonthsPerYear" runat="server">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span id="schoolActivityMonthsPerYearError" class="error" runat="server"></span>
    <br />

    <span>Date:</span>
    <span>
        <select id="schoolActivityDate" runat="server">
            <option>2005</option>
            <option>2006</option>
            <option>2007</option>
            <option>2008</option>
            <option>2009</option>
            <option>2010</option>
            <option>2011</option>
            <option>2012</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span id="schoolActivityDateError" class="error" runat="server"></span>
    <br />

    <span>Total Hours:</span>
    <span>
        <input type="text" id="schoolActivityTotalHours" runat="server" />
    </span>
    <span id="schoolActivityTotalHoursError" class="error" runat="server"></span>
    <br />

    <button type="button" id="addActivity" runat="server">Add Activity</button>
    <button type="button" id="updateActivity" runat="server" visible="false">Update Activity</button>
    <button type="button" id="cancelEditActivity" runat="server" visible="false">Cancel Editing Activity</button>
    <button type="button" id="deleteActivity" runat="server" visible="false">Delete Activity</button>
</fieldset>
```

The C# is monstrous in length, but for any brave souls:

```
void addActivity_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddSchoolActivity();
}

private bool AddSchoolActivity()
{
    ResetSchoolActivityErrors();
    SchoolActivity activityToAdd = GetSchoolActivity();

    try
    {
        SessionApplication.SchoolActivities.Add(activityToAdd);

        BindSchoolActivities();
        ResetSchoolActivityFields();
        HideSchoolActivityFields();
    }
    catch (BrokenRuleException)
    {
        MapSchoolActivityErrors(activityToAdd);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void updateActivity_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateSchoolActivity();
}

private bool UpdateSchoolActivity()
{
    ResetSchoolActivityErrors();
    SchoolActivity activityToUpdate = GetSchoolActivity();

    try
    {
        SessionApplication.SchoolActivities[schoolActivities.EditIndex] = activityToUpdate;
        ResetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex();

        BindSchoolActivities();
        ResetSchoolActivityFields();
        HideSchoolActivityFields();
    }
    catch (BrokenRuleException)
    {
        MapSchoolActivityErrors(activityToUpdate);
        SetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex(schoolActivities.EditIndex);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private SchoolActivity GetSchoolActivity()
{
    SchoolActivity currentActivity = new SchoolActivity();

    currentActivity.Details = schoolActivityDetails.Value;

    TryGetSchoolActivityMonthsPerYear(currentActivity);
    TryGetSchoolActivityDate(currentActivity);
    TryGetSchoolActivityTotalHours(currentActivity);

    return currentActivity;
}

private void TryGetSchoolActivityMonthsPerYear(SchoolActivity currentActivity)
{
    byte monthsPerYear;

    if (byte.TryParse(schoolActivityMonthsPerYear.Value, out monthsPerYear))
    {
        currentActivity.MonthsPerYear = monthsPerYear;
    }
}

private void TryGetSchoolActivityDate(SchoolActivity currentActivity)
{
    short activityDate = -1;

    if (short.TryParse(schoolActivityDate.Value, out activityDate))
    {
        currentActivity.ActivityDate = activityDate;
    }
}

private void TryGetSchoolActivityTotalHours(SchoolActivity currentActivity)
{
    short totalHours = -1;

    if (schoolActivityTotalHours.Value.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() == false
        && short.TryParse(schoolActivityTotalHours.Value, out totalHours))
    {
        currentActivity.TotalHours = totalHours;
    }
}

private void ResetSchoolActivityFields()
{
    schoolActivityDetails.Value = string.Empty;
    schoolActivityMonthsPerYear.SelectedIndex = 0;
    schoolActivityDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
    schoolActivityTotalHours.Value = string.Empty;
}

private void HideSchoolActivityFields()
{
    schoolActivityFields.Visible = false;
}

private void MapSchoolActivityErrors(int activityIndex)
{
    SchoolActivity updatedActivity = SessionApplication.SchoolActivities[activityIndex];

    MapSchoolActivityErrors(updatedActivity);
}

private void MapSchoolActivityErrors(SchoolActivity updatedActivity)
{
    foreach (RuleViolation currentViolation in updatedActivity.GetRuleViolations())
    {
        schoolActivityErrorMapping[currentViolation].InnerText = currentViolation.ErrorMessage;
    }
}

private void ResetSchoolActivityErrors()
{
    foreach (RuleViolation currentViolation in schoolActivityErrorMapping.Keys)
    {
        schoolActivityErrorMapping[currentViolation].InnerText = string.Empty;
    }
}

void schoolActivities_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (schoolActivities.EditIndex != e.NewEditIndex
        && schoolActivities.EditIndex != -1)
    {
        ResetSchoolActivityErrors();
        SchoolActivity activityToUpdate = GetSchoolActivity();

        try
        {
            SessionApplication.SchoolActivities[schoolActivities.EditIndex] = activityToUpdate;
        }
        catch (BrokenRuleException)
        {
            MapSchoolActivityErrors(activityToUpdate);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    if (e.NewEditIndex != -1)
    {
        SchoolActivity activityToEdit = SessionApplication.SchoolActivities[e.NewEditIndex];

        SetSchoolActivityFields(activityToEdit);
        ShowSchoolActivityFields();
        ShowModifyActivityButtons();
    }

    SetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex(e.NewEditIndex);
    BindSchoolActivities();
}

private void ShowModifyActivityButtons()
{
    addActivity.Visible = false;
    updateActivity.Visible = true;
    cancelEditActivity.Visible = true;
    deleteActivity.Visible = true;
}

private void SetSchoolActivityFields(SchoolActivity activityToEdit)
{
    schoolActivityDetails.Value = activityToEdit.Details;
    schoolActivityMonthsPerYear.Value = activityToEdit.MonthsPerYear.ToString();
    schoolActivityDate.Value = activityToEdit.ActivityDate.ToString();
    schoolActivityTotalHours.Value = activityToEdit.TotalHours.ToString();
}

private bool ShowSchoolActivityFields()
{
    return schoolActivityFields.Visible = true;
}

private void BindSchoolActivities()
{
    schoolActivities.DataSource = SessionApplication.SchoolActivities;
    schoolActivities.DataBind();
}

void newActivity_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SessionApplication.SchoolActivities.Count < SchoolActivityList.Rules.MaxCount)
    {
        if (schoolActivities.EditIndex != -1)
        {
            if (UpdateSchoolActivity() == false)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (schoolActivityFields.Visible)
        {
            if (AddSchoolActivity() == false)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        ShowSchoolActivityFields();
        ShowAddActivityButtons();
    }
}

private void ShowAddActivityButtons()
{
    addActivity.Visible = true;
    updateActivity.Visible = false;
    cancelEditActivity.Visible = false;
    deleteActivity.Visible = false;
}

void ResetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex()
{
    SetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex(-1);
}

void SetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex(int rowIndex)
{
    schoolActivities.EditIndex = rowIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. I missed a call to my binding function.

`UpdateSchoolActivity()` should look like this:

```
private bool UpdateSchoolActivity()
{
    ResetSchoolActivityErrors();
    SchoolActivity activityToUpdate = GetSchoolActivity();

    try
    {
        SessionApplication.SchoolActivities[schoolActivities.EditIndex] = activityToUpdate;
        ResetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex();

        BindSchoolActivities();
        ResetSchoolActivityFields();
        HideSchoolActivityFields();
    }
    catch (BrokenRuleException)
    {
        MapSchoolActivityErrors(activityToUpdate);
        SetSchoolActivitiesEditIndex(schoolActivities.EditIndex);
        BindSchoolActivities(); // That little guy? Don't worry about that little guy.
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Lol I sometimes see my issues only after I've posted as well :D